# Cannot calculate percentage?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of column but the function did not work.

Here is my dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ngoduyha/real-estate-sale-us

Here is my function:

```
sale <- read_csv("re_sale.csv")

sale %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Property Type`)) %>%  
  group_by(`Property Type`) %>% 
  summarize(sale_vol = n(), percent = sale_vol/sum(sale_vol)*100)
```

And it resulted like this:

[image]

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are dividing sale_vol by the sum of sale_vol within each group, which means you are always dividing the number by itself, resulting in 1, i.e. 100%. . Try ```percent = sale_vol / sum(!is.na(sale$`Property Type`)) * 100```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ungrouping after summarising the data. Then yes, compute the percentages.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(tidyverse)
)

sale %>% 
  filter(!is.na(`Property Type`)) %>%  
  group_by(`Property Type`) %>% 
  summarize(sale_vol = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(percent = sale_vol/sum(sale_vol)*100) 
## A tibble: 12 × 3
#   `Property Type`  sale_vol   percent
#   <chr>               <int>     <dbl>
# 1 ""                 382446 38.4     
# 2 "Apartments"          486  0.0487  
# 3 "Commercial"         1981  0.199   
# 4 "Condo"            105420 10.6     
# 5 "Four Family"        2150  0.216   
# 6 "Industrial"          228  0.0229  
# 7 "Public Utility"        5  0.000501
# 8 "Residential"       60728  6.09    
# 9 "Single Family"    401612 40.3     
#10 "Three Family"      12586  1.26    
#11 "Two Family"        26408  2.65    
#12 "Vacant Land"        3163  0.317
```

Comment: It works, I am very appreciative of your help! I struggled for an hour with this